# Doubly-periodic complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a function(s) $f(z + \sin i) = f(z)$  and $ f(z + \cos i) = f(z)$, such that $f$ is an analytical function.

Comment: Or just $f(z) = 3$.

Comment: $f(z) = 3$ is analytic.

Comment: Sometimes I overlook the most obvious answers, thanks

Comment: I presume that @Gae.S. gave the answer before the question was modified to include "$f$ analytic"?

Answer (score 2):

This says you want a function that is periodic with periods $\sin(\mathrm{i})$ and $\cos(\mathrm{i})$, so [doubly periodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_periodic_function).  The easiest periodic functions are constant functions, as observed in comments to the Question.

Continuing...

It is a standard theorem that a nonconstant meromorphic doubly periodic function cannot be bounded, otherwise, by Liouville's theorem, it is constant.  So for non-constant solutions, the function is not bounded.  If the function is not bounded, it has non-removable singular points.  Such a function is not analytic at those points, so the only such functions meeting the requirement of analyticity are constant functions.

If "$f$ is analytic" is relaxed to "$f$ is meromorphic", then various [elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function) are solutions.